# No Entity Data Model option in Data Source Configuration Wizard

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dataset, visual-studio-2013, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using Visual Studio 2013 [Ultimate] and I want to develop a database application using Entity Framework.

I have just created a Windows Form application. When I try to add a new data source I have no "Entity Data Model" option but only "Dataset" option in "Data Source Configuration Wizard".

So, what is to be configured to appear "Entity Data Model" option in configuration wizard.

I am usin .Net Framework 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Choose: Add New Item, Data, ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: But why I am wondering why the Data Source Configuration Wizard is not showing the option Entity Data Model in this or any other new project I create.

Comment: @yonjans I am having exactly the same problem and still no answer, any luck?